# Kafka quits unexpectedly in Intellij but not in bash

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, akka, lagom

When I try to run "runAll" in Lagom from within Intellij, Kafka server is closed unexpectedly right after starting Cassandra. Once I get to the line that reads "Services started, press enter to stop and go..." it automatically generated a "Stopping Services" message, even though I do not touch the keypad.

The problem does not occur when I run "runAll" from a bash shell. Also, I do not encounter this problem on my MacOS. The problem only occurs on my PC.

**EDIT**

**Firstly**, I just noticed that the unexpected Kafka server closing does not happen when I do a snbt clean and compile from terminal. For some reason, clean and compile is not happening automatically with "runAll".

**Secondly**, even without the Kafka server closing issue (as per **firstly**), the rest of the problem originally described still occurs. Seems to be an Intellij sbt shell issue? If so, why does it not occur on my Mac?